# Regex to find multi line match by negating a word

Tags: regex

I have the below code

BLOCK 1

```
   </config>
    <pd:inputBindings>
        <xmlString>
            <xsl:value-of select="$JMS-Queue-Receiver/ns:ActivityOutput/Body"/>
        </xmlString>
    </pd:inputBindings>
</pd:activity>
<pd:activity name="Checkpoint">
```

BLOCK 2

```
    </config>
        <pd:inputBindings>
            <Telegence>
                <xsl:for-each select="$Start/group/CHANGE_MDN">
                    <CHANGE_MDN>
                    <EVENT_TYPE>
```

i'm using the regex to select the from the BLOCK 2 ,

```
    <pd:inputBindings>
            <Telegence>
```

if we see the block 1 below we have the same set of items,

```
  <pd:inputBindings> 
        <xmlString>
```

so i want to select the block 2 piece based on the next line , if we see the block 1 we have `<xsl:value-of` , so we should not select from the block 1. if we see the block 2 we have `<xsl:for-each` so that needs to be select.

So i want to select by negating the `<xsl:value-of` . 
i tried with the below regex but it selects both the blocks.

```
<pd:inputBindings>[\r\n <]+[[:word:]]+>[\r\n <]+(?!xsl:value-of)
```

Comment: *"i'm using the regex to select the from the BLOCK 2"* Can you please rephrase your question? It's hard to make any sense of it.

Comment: I want to select the block 2 piece based on the next line , if we see the     block 1 we have "<xsl:value-of" , so we should not select from the block 1. if we see the block 2 we have <xsl:for-each so thats needs to be select.
So i want to select by negating the "<xsl:value-of" .

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jQ2lD6/1